# MFC losing Unicode text

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I have a MFC dialog:

UNICODE and _UNICODE are defined.

```
class VerifyComp : public CDialog
{
public:
  CString m_VerifyText;
  virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
};

void VerifyComp::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
  m_VerifyText = L"Ø2.0 X 4.1";
  pDx->m_bSaveAndValidate = 0;
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_VERIFY_TEXT, m_VerifyText);
  pDx->m_bSaveAndValidate = 1;
  DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_VERIFY_TEXT, m_VerifyText);
}
```

The result is m_VerifyText == L"O2.0 X 4.1";
I *expect* m_VerifyText is unchanged.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The resource script is a mandatory part of a [mcve]. Please add a minimal version of it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a property in the dialog .rc file that is causing the problem.

[image]

OEM Convert was set to true.  It needs to be false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that just because you have a wide-character literal does not mean the file itself can handle Unicode characters.

To fix this save the file using a Unicode character set. Go to File->Save As, right click on 'Save', select 'Save with encoding' then hit 'yes'. Now from the list of encodings choose one of the Unicode options (I generally prefer utf-8 with signature).